# Перенос проекта на dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Такой вопрос, в проекте я использую метод для проверки работы сервиса,я вынес его в отдельный класс с аннотацией @Module:

```
    @Module
    public class IsMyServiceRunning  {
        Context context;

        public IsMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) {
            isMyServiceRunnin(serviceClass);
            this.context = context;
        }


        public boolean isMyServiceRunnin(Class<?> serviceClass) {


            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                    .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;


        }

}
```

в главной активити я пишу:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

@Inject
IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning;
```

Создал класс

```
 @Module
public class AndroidModule {
    Context context;

    public AndroidModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    NotificationManagerCompat manager (Context context) {
        return (NotificationManagerCompat) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }


    @Singleton
    IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning(Context context){
        return ;//не знаю как правильно возвращать,а главное что именно
    }
}
```

Проверить работоспособность на данном этапе не могу т.к много частей не реализовано, вот и уточняю, правильно ли использую Dependency Injection вот на этом примере?
все ли я реализовал ?

**UPDATE:**

```
 @Module
public class IsMyServiceRunning  {
    Context context;

    public IsMyServiceRunning(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }


    public boolean isMyServiceRunnin(Class<?> serviceClass) {


        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;


    }

}
```

Module:

```
     @Module
    public class AndroidModule {
        Context context;

        public AndroidModule(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
        @SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        NotificationManagerCompat manager (Context context) {
            return (NotificationManagerCompat) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

    @Singleton
    IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass){
        return isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Mainactivity:

```
 @Inject
IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning;
```

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Необходимо создать отдельный класс-модуль, в котором будет метод возвращающий объект ```IsMyServiceRunning```. Либо над конструктором класса ```IsMyServiceRunning``` необходимо поставить аннотацию Inject, но тогда нужен модуль, который умеет предоставлять контекст.

Comment: ` @Singleton
    IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning(Context context){
        return ;
    }`
@ temq 
не уверен,что я так написал

Comment: Покажите полный код, сейчас ничего не понятно.

Comment: @ temq
обновил полностью код

Comment: Ну так создайте там новый объект IsMyServiceRunning и верните его. Единственное что меня смущает, это конструктор этого класса, а именно наличием бесполезного вызова метода isMyServiceRunnin для которого вы передаете в конструктор параметр Class. Я думаю это можно удалить.

Comment: @temq
обновил шапку

Comment: Должно быть ```return new IsMyServiceRunning(context)```. Вообщем, если не понятно, то вечером попробую написать ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В терминологии даггера есть такие понятия как компонент и модуль.

Модуль это та часть, которая отвечает за создание объектов, которые требует тот или иной компонент приложения.

Компонент это некоторый мост между модулями и классами которые требуют те или иные зависимости.

Исходя из этого вам необходимо создать модуль:

```
@Module
public class AndroidModule {

    private final Context context;

    public AndroidModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provide
    IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning(){
        return new IsMyServiceRunning(context);
    }

    // остальной код создания нужных объектов
}
```

Компонент:

```
@Component(modules = AndroidModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity)
}
```

И дальше уже в activity можно попросить даггер предоставить необходимую зависимость:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    @Inject
    IsMyServiceRunning isMyServiceRunning;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanse) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        ApplicationComponent component = // где то инитим и получаем компонент
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** код инициализации компонентов может отличаться, и зависит от имен компонентов и требуемых им модулей, но в данном примере выглядел бы примерно так:

```
ApplicationComponent component = new DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
    .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(application))
    .build()
```

Вообще уже написано достаточное количество статей по даггеру на том же самом [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/search/?target_type=posts&q=Dagger2&order_by=date), советую ознакомиться.

Comment: `ApplicationComponent component = `// где то инитим и получаем компонент`
        `component.inject(this);`

не понял,что после = указывать

Comment: @upward код который инициализирует компонент

Comment: @upward обновил ответ